# Is $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2\times ....}$ isomorphic to (P($\mathbb{N}$) , $\Delta$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2\times ....}$ isomorphic to (P($\mathbb{N}$) , $\Delta$)? Where P($\mathbb{N}$) is power set of natural numbers and $\Delta$ is symmetric difference between two sets.

Comment: @5xum Sorry, I was thinking of the direct sum rather than the direct product for some reason.

Comment: @M.Vinay Yes, indeed.

Comment: I think $$\;\left(P(\Bbb N),\Delta\right)\cong\prod_{i\in\Bbb R}\left(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right)_i$$ which is a cartesian product indexed by the reals ( or by any other set of cardinality $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ ) . In the question it *seems to be* a numerable cartesian product.

Comment: Identify $P(\mathbb{N})$ with the set of (abstract) functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, recast $\Delta$ accordingly, and be careful about distinguishing the direct sum from the direct product.

Comment: @Joanpemo No, now you are getting too large cardinality.

Comment: "Direct sum, direct product" usually make problems as many relate them to how is the group operation expressed. I'd rather go with the russians in this: cartesian product = irrestricted product, and direct product (or sum) = only a finite number of non-one (or non-zero) coordinates.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. Perhaps so, as the cartesian product of $\;\aleph_0\;$ copies of $\;\{0,1\}\;$ has already $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ elements.

Comment: @Joanpemo The main issue with these terms is that the categorical versions behave so differently depending on whether the groups are abelian, so while the restricted direct product is the coproduct for abelian groups, it is not the case for non-abelian ones.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Try to find the most natural bijection between the two sets. Think about characteristic functions, i.e. functions that are equal to $1$ if al element is in a set and $0$ otherwise.

Then, check if what you found is already a homomorphism.

Comment: I think you mean either homomorphism or isomorphism in the end.

Comment: (ohh, and I was about to comment that you should have left your previous comment as it had the answer, but of course it is better to have it here as an actual answer).

Comment: Further hint: Think of finite analogues. For a finite set $A$ with $n$ elements, $\mathcal P(A)$ is a group under $\Delta$. Is this isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_2)^n$? (Or equivalently, to the group of all binary strings of length $n$ under $\oplus$, the "bitwise XOR" operation).